# Extract the value of field in php and save

Tags: php, yii

Hello I have a textArea `sms` and another textfield `sms_count`..

The value of `sms_count` is like this `Used: 0/765 (1/5) | Left: 765` Whenever user type anything in textArea `sms` it counts the characters and shows it in `sms_count`

if user has typed 30 characters so far, so the value of sms_count will be like this `Used: 30/765 (1/5) | Left: 765`

When clicking on submit button, I get the value of sms_count like this..

```
sms_count => Used: 30/765 (1/5) | Left: 735
```

How do i get the characters that he entered which is 30, I need to save the value `1` in `(1/5)` only instead of `Used: 30/765 (1/5) | Left: 748`

I need to get only the used value which is `1` in this case but it can be different... if user type more than 160 characters then sms_count value will be `2` (2/5) then again if user has enter more than 320 characters then value be `3` in (3/5)

example 
30/765 (1/5) | Left: 735
161/765 (2/5) | Left: 604
330/765 (3/5) | Left: 435

So how do i extract those values in save in database through PHP?

Below is the screenshot of two fields one is textArea `sms` and textfield `sms_count`

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
<?PHP echo $form->textArea($model, 'sms', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'Campaigns_welcome_sms', 'onpaste' => "return textCounter(this.form.Campaigns_welcome_sms,this.form.smsAndCharactersCount,this.form.smsAndCharactersCount);", 'onkeyup'=>"textCounter(this.form.Campaigns_welcome_sms,this.form.smsAndCharactersCount,this.form.smsAndCharactersCount);", 'onkeypress'=>"textCounter(this.form.Campaigns_welcome_sms,this.form.smsAndCharactersCount,this.form.smsAndCharactersCount);")); ?>                        
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'sms_count', array('class' => 'form-control', 'style'=>"width: 370px", 'id'=>"smsAndCharactersCount", 'value'=>"Used: 0/765 (1/5) | Left: 765", 'readonly'=>"readonly")); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little bit of string manipulation you can extract the numbers you want like this:

```
$sms_count = 'Used: 30/765 (1/5) | Left: 735'; // YOUR VARIABLE FROM SUBMITTED DATA 

$sms = explode('/',$sms_count); // SPLIT STRING TO ARRAY BY SLASHES:    

//CREATE VARIABLE $user THAT CONTAINS THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS USED:
$used = substr($sms[0], stripos($sms[0],' ')+1); //FINDS THE SPACE ' ' AND RETURNS THE REST OF THE STRING STARTING FROM THERE...

//CREATE VARIABLE $count THAT CONTAINS THE NEXT NUMBER YOU WANT:
$count = substr($sms[1], -1, 1); // EXTRACTS THE LAST CHARACTHER/NUMBER
```

You could use `echo 'used: '. $used .' count: '.$count;` to check if the results is what you are after. In this case i would output: `used: 30 count: 1`

How you choose to save this to your database depends on your setup. It's just an ordinary insert or update query to make. A regular SQL insert query would be something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (identifier, used, counts)
        VALUES ('$identifier', '$used', '$count')";
```